# How to find an error in Linq using PropertyValidationErrors when key is not found in results

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code which will find an error if results contains the key. It will then select the count of errors:

```
var foundError = results
    .Where(e => e.PropertyValidationErrors.Keys.Contains(id))
     .Select(e => e.PropertyValidationErrors[id]).ToList();
```

I want to instead find an error if the id is not found in the results.
I'm not sure of the syntax. I want to do something like this:

```
// This is not correct, but similar to what I want to do
var foundError = results
    .WhereNot(e => e.PropertyValidationErrors.Keys.Contains(id))
     .Select(e => e.PropertyValidationErrors[id]).ToList();
```

Please advise on the syntax. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just do

```
var foundError = results
    .Where(e => !e.PropertyValidationErrors.Keys.Contains(id))
    .Select(e => e.PropertyValidationErrors).ToList();
```

and it will select all PropertyValidationErrors for objects that don't contain a propertyValidationError with the selected key.

Comment: I also could do this, but the Select did not work on it:  var foundError = !results.Any(e => e.PropertyValidationErrors.Keys.Contains(id));